# Input type range Onchange event is not fired on Chrome mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

When using Chrome for Android (or the reactive developer mode in desktop), tapping on the padding of a custom styled `input[type=range]` will move the slider, but not fire the `onchange` event immediately after tap release. The event is fired once the slider is unfocused (by tapping on a different element). Tapping the slider bar itself will show the expected behavior.

Is anyone aware as to: A. is this intended behavior? B. How can I get the expected behavior? Using oninput is not easily possible as I only need the event when the tap is released.

Firefox behaves as expected (desktop and mobile versions were tested).
Chrome Desktop v75.0 behaves as expected.
Also attempted using CSS `:after` syntax to add a pseudo-element in order to increase the tappable area. In that case, the slider position will update, but neither event handler will work.

Full MCVE:

https://jsfiddle.net/vgw6m3Lu/

https://pastebin.com/qabLtH46/

```html
<form onchange="onFormChange();">
    <div class="ctrlwrap">
      <p>Test slider</p>
      <input id="slider" onchange="onSliderChange();" oninput="onSliderInput();" max="255" min="1" type="range" value="128" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

Expected: Tap and release the padding of the slider (pink background color). The slider will update and the `onchange` event will be fired immediately.

Actual: The slider will update, but stay in focus. The `onchange` event will only fire once a different page element is tapped.